# How can I change users' notification settings for a channel via a bot?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

Does anyone know if it's possible to adjust text-channel notifications via a discord bot?

I intend to have a message for each text channel with a reaction to mute/unmute the corresponding channel; my bot would listen for the reaction and then adjust the users settings accordingly. I have tried to search the DiscordJS documentation for an answer but can't find anything related.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please could you provide some of code (if you have any)?

Comment: I don't have any code since I have no idea if there is even functionality for it (adjusting a users notification settings). I was asking if anyone had any idea if discordJs even provides functionality for adjusting a users notification settings for guild text channels.

Comment: Ok thats cool, just wanted to know. You could manually call the API endpoint for updating channel notifications with your bot token as the authentication (like when you change it as a user but use your bot token instead of your token). I'm not sure it'd work but you could try :)

Comment: I do not believe this is possible since its managed much simpler by the Discord Client, just right click a channels name and click mute on desktop or hold down a channels name on mobile and click mute. You can set a default for the guild using code as shown [here](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/guild#guild-object-default-message-notification-level), but otherwise there is no reason to manually manage client side notifications for each user. You would honestly be better off making a command that just posts directions to mute a channel.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.